# Remove a specific commit from a branch

Tags: git, github, branch

How do I remove a specific commit from a branch after I pushed it?

Suppose I have a history like this (from latest to oldest) in the remote repository called `v0.1`and I would like to remove `765th4` from `v0.1`, without removing it from other branch. How do I achieve this?

```
2fsf34 
32t6e0
54r346
765th4
9r34gg
```

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest bet here is to *not* actually remove the `765th4` commit from your `v0.1` branch, but rather to *revert* it using `git revert`.  Try the following command:

```
# from v0.1 branch
git revert 765th4
```

If you run `git log` after running the above, you will notice that a *new* commit has been made to your `v0.1` branch, such that the history now looks something like:

```
abc123
2fsf34 
32t6e0
54r346
765th4
9r34gg
```

Here `abc123` is the SHA-1 for the revert commit which now sits on the HEAD of your `v0.1` branch.  This commit functionally undoes everything which the `765th4` commit introduced.  This has the same effect as completely removing the `765th4` commit, without the potentially bad side effects.

If you really wanted to excise the `765th4` commit, you could doing an interactive rebase.  However, this generally is not recommended for branches which you have already pushed to the remote.  The reason is that rewriting history can cause problems for anyone besides yourself who might already be using the `v0.1` branch.  So, stick with `git revert` for a simple and safe option here.

Comment: Thank you for your response! After `git revert`, do I just do `git push -u origin v0.1`?